# TYPO3 Pagination First Page

Tags: php, typo3-8.x

Easy way to get First Page in TYPO3 with Pagination Widget or without?

Im trying to show something only in the first page . Its inside a for loop but with pagination comes in the other Pages too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to evaluate the `page` parameter (no value greater than 1). Maybe you need to store it with typoscript in your fluid variables for the template. at least in the `settings`.